# How to expand $PWD when using tab to autocomplete?

Tags: bash

When I was using my Ubuntu system, I could type `cd $PWD/` and when I hit TAB, the $PWD would change to the actual working directory I was in; for example, `cd /home/daverbuj/`.

Now that I've changed computers and no longer using Ubuntu, I can't replicate this feature. Is there some way to configure my .bashrc or something similar to autocomplete/expand my paths that I use?

Comment: That sounds like a shell specific functionality, what shell were you using on your UBUNTU machine and what shell are you on now? Bash?

Comment: You want to add `shopt -s direxpand` to your startup files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `shopt -s direxpand` to your rc files.